# How to convert smileys to emoticon?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, emoticons

Is there a way to convert ":)" to  like : [detection and conversion](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/auto-replace-emoji-messages-mac.gif), I have a `UITextView` in a chat application which should convert the smiley to the respective emoticon.

Comment: You can either find a third party code that does it (which is not a SO allowed question), or you have to implement it yourself, and it's about parsing/detecting, and replacing, but you have to make the whole list (detect/replacement) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Get the offical list: [emoji](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

Just an example: `yourTextView.text = "your smiley: \u{1f642}"`

If you want to convert emoticons to emoji on the fly either you need to specify it by yourself and analyze the input string or using a 3rd-party lib e.g. [pods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Emoji-swift) for converting and watching input string through text change events e.g.: [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate)

Comment: I don't want a single emoticon, all of them should be detected and converted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic in this package npm, you find also a map of smile and the respective emoji:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/smile2emoji

Answer (score 0):

I have created this simple class based on the npm package suggested by @emish89 https://www.npmjs.com/package/smile2emoji.

https://gist.github.com/lorenzOliveto/f20a89e9f68276cae21497a177ad8a4c

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

You should implement delegate `textViewDidChange` for your `UITextView` and find all need substrings in its text then replace them inside with `textStorage` property:

```swift
extension ViewController : UITextViewDelegate {
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        guard let text = textView.text else { return }
        
        var index = text.startIndex
        while let range = text.range(of: ":)", range: index..<text.endIndex) {
            index = range.upperBound
            textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(range, in: text), with: "")
        }
    }
}
```

It works while editing or paste text.